# Code optimization (for-loops) to increase performance applying functions to submatrices

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, matrix, optimization

I have written some code that needs 10 minutes to terminate which is way to long for my application. I guess that the 2 for loops can be optimized but I don't know how.

Here is what it should do:

Given a matrix L (numpy), I create 2 other matrices "votes" and "zeros" with same shape. Now I want to apply a function over every 8x8 window of the image (overlapping). With the 8x8 result matrix, I want to store some information in the "votes" and "zeros" matrices at the same position where the 8x8 window is.

The following code shows the algorithm in detail and works just fine but very slow:

```
def compute_grid_votes(path):
    
    # Load image and convert to float32
    L = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.float32)

    # Initialize votes and zeros
    votes = np.empty_like(L, dtype=np.int16)
    votes[:] = -1
    zeros = np.zeros_like(L)

    # Loop over all 8x8 blocks
    for i in range(0, L.shape[0]-8):
        for j in range(0, L.shape[1]-8):
            
            # Compute DCT of the block
            dct_block = cv2.dct(L[i:i+8, j:j+8])

            # Compute number of zeros in the block
            z = np.sum(np.abs(dct_block) < 0.5)

            # Vote for grid aligned with block
            non_valids = (z == zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8])
            votes[i:i+8, j:j+8][non_valids] = -1
            
            mask = (z > zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8])
            votes[i:i+8, j:j+8] = mask* (8*(i%8) + (j%8)) + (1 - mask)*votes[i:i+8, j:j+8]
            zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8] = mask* z + (1 - mask)*zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8]
    
    return votes
```

Comment: take a look at `numba` package. Also, first its best to use `line_profiler` to check where is your main performance issue. Multiprocessing should give you some improvement (you can use parallel computing from numba too)

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the "np.where" function. This should eliminate explicit loops over the blocks, resulting in increased performance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def compute_grid_votes(path):
    # Load image and convert to float32
    L = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.float32)

    # Initialize votes and zeros
    votes = np.full_like(L, -1, dtype=np.int16)
    zeros = np.zeros_like(L)

    # Loop over all 8x8 blocks
    for i in range(0, L.shape[0]-8):
        for j in range(0, L.shape[1]-8):
            # Compute DCT of the block
            dct_block = cv2.dct(L[i:i+8, j:j+8])

            # Compute number of zeros in the block
            z = np.sum(np.abs(dct_block) < 0.5)

            # Vote for grid aligned with block
            mask = z > zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8]

            votes[i:i+8, j:j+8] = np.where(mask, 8*(i%8) + (j%8), votes[i:i+8, j:j+8])
            zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8] = np.where(mask, z, zeros[i:i+8, j:j+8])

    return votes
```